# MS Access - Forms, New Records, and Displaying Data Fields from various tables

Tags: ms-access

I have created the following model in MS Acces:
[image]

What I am trying to implement in the Forms is the functionality to enter a Service request (which esssentially contains only text fields and ID) and then (on the **same** form) to map other information (such as Requestor, Business Unit, Status, Journey) to the new service request.

I have succeeded to enter most of the information in the TBL_Star_Request:
[image]

The problem is that (according to my current model) a serivice request needs to be created prior to populating the TBL_Star_Request table.
Ideally, I am trying to insert both (new service request in table TBL_Service_Requests AND to populate the TBL_Star_Request table) on the same form.

My question is: is this a good design? Can you suggest some better more intuitive solution and describe how to do it? Will it require model adaptation?

And secondly, how can I implement a construct (and which) in order to simply list all the existing service requests by making a star join and selecting the most important attributes from each of the tables shown in the model?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you add Service Request data as a child subform? In this case, the user will be able to add a few service requests and creating order won't be important.

Comment: I think TBL_Star_Request would be the subform. Model looks fine but then I don't know what "Star" and "Service" requests are nor why they are related. Build a query and a report to display related data.

Comment: I just do not understand why it is so complicated in Excel to implement a functionality in which I have (simplified) two tables TBL_Service_Requests (text fields and attachments) and TBL_Star. (contains KPIs), and to generate a new entry in the TBL_Service_Requests table (e.g. I need a new account), and then that the PK from that table automatically gets transfered to the TBL_Star table so I can add the respecive data (who requested it, what is the status...). Seems I have to manually find the IDs and enter them. Please correct me if I am wrong. This approach does not make my life easier...

Comment: It even seems to me that the best thing would be to merge the attributes from TBL_Service_Requests with TBL_Star table... bit then the design does not look like in the "books"...

Comment: So tbl_Service_Requests is a table of unique accounts? Then you enter dependent records in tbl_Star_Requests? Use form/subform arrangement.